# detect the name of the page that the user came from

Tags: php, redirect, iis-7, http-referer

I am redirecting the pages to `404.php` if the page is not found from IIS settings.
My problem is that I would like to detect the LINK that they were looking for.

For example:

if some one access to http://www.site.com/nosuchpage it will redirect to 404.php but using `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` I am not getting url where the user came from.
Please help.

Comment: Always try var_dump($_SERVER) to see all such details.

Comment: Be aware that many users have disabled the submitting of the referrer header from in their browser.

Answer (score 2):

If you are redirecting them to `404.php` via htaccess, i.e.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Then you should just be able to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` as the URL they requested should still be the url that wasn't found.

Comment: I tried the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and I am getting the result the rquested page was: /404.php. I did the redirect using IIS settings

Comment: if I try http://www.site.com/nosuchpage , why it is showing the requested page was http://www.site.com/404.php instead of http://www.site.com/nosuchpage?

Comment: You can't be setting up the 404 document correctly. I've already outlined above how to do it using a htaccess file.